# Unable to measure the height of my Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to get the height of my Bottom Navigation Bar, so I can set a bottom margin on the content that is displayed above the bar. My problem is that it always returns 0. Here is the code :

```
navigation.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                navHeight = navigation.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
        });

        FrameLayout frame = findViewById(R.id.frame_container);
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) frame.getLayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, navHeight);
        frame.setLayoutParams(params);
```

I also tried using `ViewTreeObserver`, but it didn't work neither.

Comment: Everything after your `navigation.post()` call runs immediately; the `run()` method you've posted hasn't executed yet, so `navHeight` hasn't been set yet. One possible solution would be to move everything else to be inside of `run()`.

Comment: oooooh yes I forgot this ! I'm gonna try to fix it, I feel stupid right now xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to move everything inside the run() method